# Which is the correct word to be filled in the blank in this sentence, "use", "using", or "to use"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Touch screens are electronic visual displays that allow a user to interact directly with what is displayed on the screen, rather than ___________ a pointing device, such as a mouse.

Which is the correct word to be filled in the blank in this sentence, "use", "using", or "to use"?

I prefer to use "using", but is "use" also OK? How about "to use"?

Comment: If a two-word answer is allowed, I'd say "indirectly with" fits best.

Comment: You are comparing two ways of human–computer interaction. So, I think the full answer would be "to interact indirectly using" or "to interact indirectly with" as @DamkerngT. has pointed out. 

Now compare: "using a pointing device", "use a pointing device", and "to use a pointing device". So "using a pointing device" is the best because it has the same meaning as "to interact indirectly using a pointing device"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/rather) has an entry for this. It says...

> We use rather than to give more importance to one thing when ***two alternatives*** or preferences are being compared:

Good to note that when we use ***'rather than' with a verb,*** which is the case here, we use the base form or *(less commonly)* the -ing form of a verb.

For example...

> I would prefer to leave now rather than *<del>to</del>* wait.

[Another reference](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/rather-than.htm) with good information is here.

> Rather than is normally used in parallel structures: for example with two adjectives, adverbs, nouns, infinitives or -ing forms. When the main clause has a to-infinitive, rather than is normally followed by an infinitive without to. An -ing form is also possible.

So, to answer your question, it could be simply *'use'* **OR** *'using'*.

Comment: my guess was use

Comment: @learner And your guess matches the *grammarians* lol :)

Answer (score 4):

Robert Burchfield says that *rather than* can be followed by an *-ing* form, a bare infinitive or a *to-* infinitive. He suggests that "matching forms are best in in the clause preceding and following *rather than*". If you follow Burchfield's advice, *to use*, matching *to interact*, is the best form.

Burchfield R (1996.652), *The New Fowler's Modern English Usage.*

Comment: I don't think it's about matching "interact". The sentence lists two variants of interaction: "interact directly" and "interact using a pointing device", so the best form is "using" - second "interact" is ellipsed, while "using" remains "using".

Comment: You could also say "rather than having to use", but the "V-ing" construction is still there.

Answer (score 1):

'To use' would be the most structurally correct, since it's being compared in preference to the infinitive, 'to interact'. However, it's totally permissible to compare an infinitive to a participle. 'Using' yields the best conversational flow.